# Multi dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my `Ajax.BeginForm`i have a dropdown list where i can load a partial view when user select an item from that list.
It works fine however i would like to do the following:
When user select option number 3 in the list, i would like to show another dropdownlist

Is this possible?

Here is my code

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Report", "Home", new { }, new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        OnBegin = "AjaxBegin",
        OnComplete = "AjaxComplete",
        OnSuccess = "LoadSuccess",
        OnFailure = "LoadFailure",
        UpdateTargetId = "result",

    }, new { @class = "form-horizontal form-small" }
        ))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReportId)

        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedOptionId, Model.ReportOption, new { onchange = "$(this.form).submit();", @class = "form-control input-sm" })
        </div>
    <div id="cat" class="col-md-9">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedOptionId, Model.CatOption, new { onchange = "$(this.form).submit();", @class = "form-control input-sm" })
        </div>

    }
```

**UPDATE**
Following your advices i changed the code to the following

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedOptionId, Model.ReportOption, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCatId, Model.LotOptions, new { @class = "hidden form-control input-sm" })

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Report", "Home", new { }, new AjaxOptions
            {
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                OnBegin = "AjaxBegin",
                OnComplete = "AjaxComplete",
                OnSuccess = "LoadSuccess",
                OnFailure = "LoadFailure",
                UpdateTargetId = "result",

            }, new { @class = "form-horizontal form-small" }
                ))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdReport)

                <input id="subButon" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            }

        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#SelectedOptionId").change(function() {
                var value = $("#SelectedOptionId").val();
                if (value == "3") {
                    $("#SelectedCatId").removeClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $("#SelectedCatId").addClass('hidden');
                }

            });
        });
```

However when i submit, both `SelectedOptionId , SelectedCatId` are set to null
Any idea?

Comment: You can use JS with `hide()` or `show()` method for client-side visibility handling. But which "another" dropdownlist you want to show?

Comment: Do not submit a form on the `change()` event of a `<select>` - use a submit button. If the user uses the arrow keys to navigate through the options, the submit will be fired on the first key stroke!

Comment: Just updated my code with both dropdownlists

Comment: You cannot bind 2 dropdownlists to the same property (only the first one will ever be bound). You need a separate property to bind the 2nd one to (and preferably a `[RequiredIf]` attribute to ensure an option in the 2nd is selected if the first option is `3`)

Comment: Sounds like OP needs "cascading dropdownlist" - handle `change` event of the first DDL (don't use submit form as Stephen said, but use `jQuery.ajax()` call), then pass first DDL's selected value with `data` parameter to action method & populate second DDL with `List<SelectListItem>` (ensure they're bound to different properties too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achive that behavior calling a custom function in `onchange` event.

**In your view**

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedOptionId, Model.ReportOption, new { onchange = "onChange(this);", @class = "form-control input-sm" })
</div>
<div id="cat" class="col-md-9">
    <!-- Consider use another property for this dropdown. Note the 'hidden' class which makes the dropdown hidden. -->
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedOptionId, Model.CatOption, new { onchange = "onChangeCat(this)", @class = "form-control input-sm hidden" })
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function onChange(sender) {
    var dropdown = $(sender);

    //Selected value in SelectedOptionId dropdown
    var selectedValue = dropdown.val();

    var catDropDownList = $('#cat #SelectedOptionId');

    if (selectedValue === "3") {
        catDropDownList.removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        catDropDownList.addClass('hidden');

        //Submit the form
        dropdown.parents('form').submit();
    }

}

function onChangeCat(sender) {
    //Code executed when the selected value of the second dropdown change.
}
```

**Attention:** using two `DropDownListFor` for the same property causes the generation of two element with the same id (`SelectedOptionId` in this case). You should avoid that and use a property for each dropdown.

You should check the first dropdown value to show/hide the second dropdown when the page is loaded.

**Answer to question update**

Dropdown values are not sent because they are not nested in the form.